# About $\lim_{n\to +\infty} n\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos^2(k)$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series

In my research work, I need to show that the sequence $(nu_n)$  tends to 0 where $ (u_n)$ is defined by  $$u_{n+1}=u_{n} \cos^{2}(n),\quad  u_{0}=1$$
$(u_n)$ is a positive and decreasing sequence. My adempt \begin{align*}
u_{n+1}&= \prod_{k=1}^n\cos^2(k)  =(\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{e^{k i } + e^{- k i }}{2} )^2 \\
 &= 4^{-n}e^{-2(1+2+\cdots+n) \cdot i } \prod_{k=1}^n \left( 1 + e^{2 k i } \right)^2  \\
&=4^{-n}e^{-n(n+1)\cdot i } \prod_{k=1}^n \left( 1 + e^{2 k i } \right)^2 
\end{align*}  Afterwards, I don't see how to continue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It follows from the irrationality of $\pi$ and [Weyl's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Weyl%27s_criterion) that the positive integers are equidistributed modulo $\pi$. In particular, asymptotically one-third of the integers $k\in\{1,\dotsc,n-1\}$ satisfy that $k\bmod\pi$ lies in $[\pi/3,2\pi/3]$. It follows, for $n$ large, that
$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos^2(k)\leq 2^{-n/2}$. Hence the limit in the original question equals zero.

**Remark.** From $\int_0^\pi\ln(\cos^2(x))\,dx=-\pi\ln 4$ it even follows that $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos^2(k)\leq 4^{-(1+o(1))n}$.

Comment: Thank you, I took my time, I understood

Answer (score 5):

It is  graphically evident and easy to prove that if for $\theta\in\mathbb R$ one has $\cos^2\theta \ge c:=\cos^2\frac12=0,7701\dotso<1$, then $|\cos^2(\theta+1)|\le c$. As a consequence the number of integers $k\in\{0,\dotsc,n-1\}$ such that $\cos^2 k\ge c $  is at most $n/2$ (in fact it is even larger, due to the uniform distribution of $e^{2ki}$ on the circle). This ensures the product for $c_n$ an exponential decay, so that $nc_n=o(1)$.

Comment: (sorry, I had a crush while editing)

Comment: In other words: $a_{n+2} \leqslant c a_n$ for $c = \max (\cos^2(x) \cos^2(x+1)) < 1$.

Comment: Exact, $c=0.5931..$

Comment: Nice elementary argument. It is similar to my answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/235508/does-sum-n-frac-sin-nn-converge-absolutely

Comment: Indeed it's the same argument