# Find better than $ 4^n\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos^2(k)\sim e^{o(n)}$

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, diophantine-approximation

Let $$u_n=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos^2(k)$$ then $$\frac1n \ln(u_n) = \frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  \ln(\cos^2(k)) \underset{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow \frac1{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \ln(\cos^2(x))\,{\rm d}x = -\ln(4)$$ We deduce that  $$\ln(u_n)\sim -n\ln(4)$$ . I think that the sequence $v_n=\ln(4^n u_n))$ have not limit , So there is no  constant c such that $u_n \sim c\,4^{-n}$.  Can we find better then $$ \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos^2(k)\sim 4^{-n}e^{o(n)}$$ . What is $\limsup 4^n u_n$ and $\liminf 4^n u_n$ ?

**additional comments**

[wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cprod_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%20%7C1%2Be%5E%7B2ik%20%7D%7C) does not confirm that $\liminf 4^n u_n  =0$[image]

Comment: You should link to this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383866

Comment: You need to be careful with the limit in your second display. If $k\bmod\pi$ gets very close to $\pi/2$ for some $k\in\{1,\dotsc,n-1\}$, then $\ln(u_n)/n$ can be much smaller than $-\ln(4)$. This is why, in my response to your previous question, I only stated $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos^2(k)\leq 4^{-(1+o(1))n}$ instead of $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos^2(k)=4^{-(1+o(1))n}$. Note that $f(x):=\ln(\cos^2(x))$ is not Riemann integrable on $[0,\pi]$, because it is not bounded there. Instead, $\int_0^\pi f$ exists as an improper Riemann integral, i.e. as $\lim_{h\to 0+}(\int_0^{\pi/2-h} f+\int_{\pi/2+h}^\pi f)$.

Comment: Thanks GH I didn't realize that f is not Riemann integrable on $I = [0,2 \ pi]$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume that exchanging the cosine by the sine will not matter for the large-$n$ behavior of the product, so let me consider
$$a_n^2=4^n\prod_{k=1}^{n}\sin^2 k=\left(\prod_{k=1}^n\left|1-e^{k\alpha \pi i}\right|\right)^2\;\;\text{with}\;\;\alpha=2/\pi.$$
The convergence of $a_n$ was determined in this [MO posting](https://mathoverflow.net/q/236689/11260) from five years ago, with lim inf $a_n$ equal to zero and lim sup $a_n$ equal to infinity for irrational $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you Carlo Beenakker  $u_n=4^n \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos^2(k)=4\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left|1+e^{2k i}\right|\right)^2$I'm trying to see how to apply the result of your link if we replace the - with the +